# Как поддерживать целостность БД в приемочных тестах?

Tags: php, codeception

Использую codeception. В приемочных тестах на API часто создаются и удаляются данные, но требуется, чтобы с каждым новым тестом БД находилась в некотором определенном состоянии. Накатывать фикстуры заново - затратно. Использовать транзакции невозможно (только в unit тестах это реально). Как можно обеспечить всегда некоторое "стандартное" состояние БД на момент запуска каждого теста?

Comment: На всякий случай спрошу: а сколько у вас приемочных тестов? Может быть у вас их слишком много и именно поэтому возникают проблемы с накатыванием дампа БД для каждого теста? Просто дамп базы - самый очевидный вариант решения проблемы. (Надеюсь, что кто-то предложит что-то еще :-))

Comment: На каждый ресурс REST API приемочный тест. У некоторых ресурсов есть параметры (вроде фильтров и т.п.), бывает несколько тестов. Много в общем

Comment: некрокомментарий: можно довести базу до определенного состояния, засунуть в докер, на каждый тест запускать новый контейнер. по скорости должно быть быстрее работы с данными.

Answer (score 1):

Серебряной пули нет. Если накатывание фикстур уже заоптимизировано напрочь, и саму фикстуру уже не уменьшить, то вариантов, по сути, немного:

- писать тесты так, чтобы они работали на любой базе с валидным
  состоянием. Концептуально это правильнее, т.к. позволяет тестировать
  систему не только в "исконно чистом виде". Особенно если тесты будут
  в произвольном порядке (обычно хватает рандомизации очередности
  разных тест-кейсов). Правда писать такие тесты сложее. Зато ошибок
  вылавливается больше.
- "доготавливать" базу в самом тесте. Чистить из базы используемые в тесте модели, обнулять счетчики, заново загружать справочники и т.д.
- генерировать базы с фикстурами еще до тестов, а непосредственно перед тестами только накатывать миграции под текущую версию